# AngularJS disable form validation while keeping the built-in browser (HTML5) validation

Tags: angularjs, html, validation, angularjs-forms

I'm using angularJS form which has three inputs - text, email and multiple email field. All the above fields are required, and Angular's validation works fine on the text and email fields, but it is not working for the multiple email field.
As far as I know, all the new browsers [supports multiple attribute on email fields](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) , but apparently AngularJS doesn't, because the `ng-model` isn't updating with the value when it "thinks" that the multiple email field isn't valid.

I tried using `novalidate` on the form, but then I have to do all the validations by myself, while all I want is to tell Angular to ignore the validity of the fields and let the browser do its thing..

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Try using the `ng-list` directive on your input field

Comment: @callmekatootie ng-list with input (type email) still invalid..